# AJAX and PHP - Need to redirect PHP page after certain criteria is met

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redirect

Ok, so I have this problem and I'm not great with Ajax yet, so I don't really know how to proceed.

I have a page that is running a refresh using Ajax and Javascript every 7 seconds.
Each time the Ajax page refreshs it removes one from a SQL value in my database.
When that value gets to 0, I need the main php page to go to a different URL.

The following code is on streets.php.
It calls streetsdo.php to display info.

```
<script>    
function findUser(str) {
    var dapage='streetsdo.php';
    var http;
    var myself = arguments.callee;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        } catch(e) {
            http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        }
    }
    if (http) {
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (/4|^complete$/.test(http.readyState)) {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = http.responseText;
                setTimeout(function(){myself();}, 7000);
            }
        };
        http.open('POST',dapage,true);
        http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        http.send('req=".$uid."&req2=numb');

    }

}
</script>
```

That is the code that does the refresh.
On streetsdo.php a MySQL query is basically counting down.
Once it hits 0, I need streets.php to go to a different URL.

Is this possible?

I tried using header("Location : blabla"), but that won't work as it only redirects the streetsdo.php page and not the streets.php where the script is running, and I get stuck in frames.

EDIT This script is activated by a button on streets.php.

```
<span id='result'><span class='Streets'>
<form method='post' action='streets.php'>

<input type='button' class='theButton' value='Start' onclick='findUser(this.value)'></form>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your countdown reaches zero, the ajax call must return a special value. You check for it replacing

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = http.responseText;
```

by

```
if(http.responseText == 'finished'){
    window.location.href = '/myotherpage.php'
} else{
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = http.responseText;
}
```

Comment: So I should add that to the original script on streets.php so if it recognizes the finished response, it will redirect, right?

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I am just not sure how to return the response to the streets.php. Am I supposed to just echo it back?

Comment: That was it. You are great, thanks so much! It's making much more sense to me now. :)

Comment: Streetdo.php returns your content while counting down. When it reaches 0 is returns that special value that triggers the redirect

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
var myTimer;
function ajaxData(){
    var result = document.getElementById("result");

    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "your php file.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var d = hr.responseText;
            for(var o in d){
                if(d[o].id){
                    result.innerHTML += '<p>'+d[o].id+'<br></p>';

                }
            }
        }
    }
    hr.send("your variable which the php will take as $_POST[]");
    result.innerHTML = "requesting...";
    myTimer = setTimeout('ajax_json_data()',7000);

}
</script>`
```

Comment: I dont think that this redirects the page as the author was asking, just cleans the code.

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for.